# How to make a contact field entry like this on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an application in which when tapping a button it will show a view to  the user to enter the contact number of the user, like in the image below. Can anybody help me achieve this? I need my users to chose their country within the flags and corresponding stdcodes needs to be there[image]

Answer (score 2):

What I see in the example: a UIImageView for the country flag, a UILabel for the country code and a UITextField with a placeholder for the phone number. You can set de value for placeholder in IB or programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a custom view for that.

Steps to do it:

- Derive a class from UIView.
- Add UIImageView, UILabel and UITextField into it.
- Layout it properly.
- On button click, show this view with proper frames/bounds.

Comment: I need that flag image to be changed,and the std codes to be displayed according to the country thats what i am asking?

Comment: For each country you can have integer value say for USA 1 and save these values in Dictionary as key USA and value 1.Then create an array of dictionary which will contain image name and country code eg: at index 1 store values for USA.So when user selects USA, you can retrieve flag image as [[myArray objectAtIndex:[myDictionary valueForKey:@"USA"] valueForKey:@"imageName"]], this will give image name at that index which you can use for [UIImage imageName:]and same for country code.So that you do not have to find out every time which country is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view like whatever you have shown and initially make it hidden, when user click on the button make the view visible.

Answer (score 0):

ON action event add this sub view into your view

Answer (score 0):

In Xib file,click the label and see the right side properties,In that properties you will find the placeholder option.In that placeholder,type the text you want.That text will be appeared as a hint for the user when he taps it.Or otherwise,directly in your code where you declare the label,in that label code

```
label.placeholder=@"Enter Contact here";
```

Comment: I think you will take the UITextField,So then UITextField *label.placeholder=@"e.g.050543432";